# android - ListView adapter with HashMap isn't displaying correctly

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm trying to create a very basic ListView dialog, where each item is to have a sub-heading. For this purpose I'm trying to use the simple_list_item_2 layout with an adapter for a List(Map(String,String)). The code is as follows:

```
public static class StoreList extends DialogFragment {
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final List<Map<String, String>> data = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

        // Dummy data
        Map<String, String> datum = new HashMap<String, String>();
        datum.put("name", "Name1");
        datum.put("address", "USA");
        data.add(datum);
        Map<String, String> datum2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
        datum.put("name", "Name2");
        datum.put("address", "CAN");
        data.add(datum2);

        // Adapter for the ListView:
        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                getActivity(), 
                data,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
                new String[] {"name", "address"},
                new int[] {android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2});

        // Listener for the ListView:
        DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), StoreActivity.class);
                Map<String, String> listItem = data.get(which);
                i.putExtra("name", listItem.get("name"));
                i.putExtra("address", listItem.get("address"));
                startActivity(i);
            }
        };

        // Build the ListView dialog:
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle(R.string.storeListTitle);
        builder.setAdapter(adapter, listener);
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

When executed, the result looks like this:

http://i.imgur.com/8gkTECe.png

As you can see, only one of the four text strings are displayed. What's going on here?

Answer (score 1):

you are setting values on datum instead of datum2.

```
   // Dummy data
Map<String, String> datum = new HashMap<String, String>();
datum.put("name", "Name1");
datum.put("address", "USA");
data.add(datum);
Map<String, String> datum2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
datum.put("name", "Name2"); //should be datum2
datum.put("address", "CAN"); //should be datum2
data.add(datum2);
```

Comment: also, i think the text color for text1 is white, which is why you are not seeing the "name"